# Handle socket connection and http request on a nodejs server

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am creating a socket connection using net module and also handling http request on the same socket but when create a post request it outputs client has connected successfully and post endpoint code doesnt run

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var net = require('net');
var clients = [];

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) {
   console.log ('client has connected successfully!');
   clients.push(connection);
   connection.write('Hello Node.js!\r\n');
   connection.pipe(connection);
});

// get all todos
app.get('/api/v1/todos', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    success: 'true',
    message: 'todos retrieved successfully'
  })
});

app.post('/getUser', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body)
      clients[0].write('CH01');
        return res.status(200).send({
      success: 'false',
      message: 'title is required'

    });

  })

server.listen(9000, function() {
   console.log('server is listening');
   console.log('server bound address is: ' + server.address ());
});
```